# Cannot export pdf highlights from Preview.app using skim in OSX10.8.3

Tags: pdf, preview, skim, highlights

When I 'convert to notes' in skim, only the page numbers of the highlighted text gets displayed. I can click on those page numbers and it will go to the highlighted part of the document but the actual text does not appear when I export notes. I just get a blank document or a page with the page numbers where the highlighted text is. Can you suggest what I'm ight be doing wrong? I'm using OSX Lion 10.8.3.

Ps. I can copy and paste text from the pdf, so it appears to have recognisable text.